# Unity animations are twitchy when transitioning/blending. Any potential fix?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Video of issue in action: https://streamable.com/pkrog

The video linked above does a better job of explaining the issue than I could, but I'll give it a shot.

I have my walking/idle animations setup in a 2D Freeform Cartesian Blend Tree, which is working perfectly, aside from when I'm moving between transitions. So idle looks great, until I hold 'W' to move forward, then for the half second it's blending between idle and walking, my model gets very twitchy, then after it's done blending, it's smooth again. Same thing happens every time the Animator has to transition between different animations.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have to do with the fact that you update your camera in fixedUpdate and your animations are updated at the game normal update rate. So the different rate at which both your animations and your movement/camera/body updates makes it jittery.

Comment: No problem! Had the same thing happen a while back and it took me a while to figure it out. The Execution order page of the Unity doc helped me to figure it out a lot. Also if you use LateUpdate for bone rotation, be careful because the animation resets bone rotation every frame. While using Ik and such you can get weird behaviour. Also curious, is this a full body animation ?